# R Shiny - Column in Conditional Panel outside Sidebar Panel

Tags: r, shiny

I am editing an existing R Shiny app: [link](https://github.com/yonicd/shinyHeatmaply/tree/master/inst/shinyapp). In `ui.R`, after line 48, I wanted to add additional information in the `conditionalPanel`. I have updated the code to look like this:

```html
conditionalPanel('input.showDendo==1',
         hr(),
         h4('Dendrogram Manipulation'),
         selectInput('dendrogram','Dendrogram Type',choices = c("both", "row", "column", "none"),selected = 'both'),
         selectizeInput("seriation", "Seriation", c(OLO="OLO",GW="GW",Mean="mean",None="none"),selected = 'OLO'),
         sliderInput('branches_lwd','Dendrogram Branch Width',value = 0.6,min=0,max=5,step = 0.1)
                 ),
         hr(),
         h4("Row Dendrogram"),
         column(
             width = 6,
             selectizeInput("distFun_col",
                            "Distance Method",
                            c(Euclidean = "euclidean",
                              Maximum = "maximum",
                              Manhattan = "manhattan",
                              Canberra = "canberra",
                              Binary = "binary",
                              Minkowski = "minkowski"),
                            selected = "euclidean"))
```

and I am unable to figure out why the drop down is "outside" the grey background of the `sideBarPanel` as seen in the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the styles of this app, you need to set column width to 12 or add another `col-sm-6` element, then add `<br>` and `<hr>`:

```r
hr(),
h4("Row Dendrogram"),
column(
  width = 12,
  selectizeInput("distFun_col",
                 "Distance Method",
                 c(Euclidean = "euclidean",
                   Maximum = "maximum",
                   Manhattan = "manhattan",
                   Canberra = "canberra",
                   Binary = "binary",
                   Minkowski = "minkowski"),
                 selected = "euclidean")),
br(),
hr(),
```

Then, it should look like this:

[image]

This happens, because the [`col-sm-*`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) classes have [`float: left;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float#values) attribute, which makes them heightless, so they overflow the parent container.

Comment: this worked! thanks for the clear explanation - helps me move other things around as well.